# Windows Batch file count numbers of tokens

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have this batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

IF EXIST OPERATORS_FULL.csv DEL OPERATORS_FULL.csv
IF EXIST OPERATORS_FULL.tmp DEL OPERATORS_FULL.tmp

FOR %%A IN ( OPERATORS_*.csv ) DO (
    :: get attribute from filename
    SET "attr=%%A"
    SET "attr=!attr:OPERATORS_=!"
    SET "attr=!attr:.csv=!"
    :: split string to get date suffix
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %%G IN ( "!attr!" ) DO (
        SET attr=%%G
        SET date_=%%H
    )
    :: dump CSVs, skipping each header line, adding the attributes from the filename
    FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %%G IN ( %%A ) DO ECHO %%G;!attr!;!date_! >> OPERATORS_FULL.tmp
)

REN OPERATORS_FULL.tmp OPERATORS_FULL.csv
```

The attr value is variable and it can contain 1,2,3,4,... of "_" character.
So the `tokens=1,2` is not functionally everytime.
I want the last token of the "attr" variable.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

I tried this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

IF EXIST Operatori_FULL.csv DEL Operatori_FULL.csv
IF EXIST Operatori_FULL.tmp DEL Operatori_FULL.tmp

FOR %%A IN ( Operatori_*.csv ) DO (
    :: get attribute from filename
    SET "attr=%%A"
    SET "attr=!attr:Operatori_=!"
    SET "attr=!attr:.csv=!"
        set "date_=!attr!"
:loop
        if "!date_:_=!" == "!date_!" goto :gotdate
        for /f "delims=_ tokens=1,*" %%g in ("!date_!") do echo %%h

pause
        goto :loop
:gotdate
        :: dump CSVs, skipping each header line, adding the attributes from the filename
    FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %%G IN ( %%A ) DO ECHO %%G;!attr!;!date_! >> Operatori_FULL.tmp
)

REN Operatori_FULL.tmp Operatori_FULL.csv
```

But the snippet remove only the first part of string (A2A_)

Comment: I have a feeling you are overthinking the solution to your problem.  If you could at least provide examples of your file names for reference and provide the output examples for those file names there may be a simpler solution. And the only reason I say this is because of these two lines of code. `SET "attr=%%A"` `SET "attr=!attr:.csv=!"`

Comment: In your last question you said: **OPERATORS_APP_MKT_XXX_yyyymmdd or can be OPERATORS_APP_XXX_yyyymmdd**.  If you are just trying to get the date from the file name which is always in a yyyymmdd format, why don't you just use a substring to get the last 8 characters from the file name. `SET "date_=!attr:~-8!"

Answer (score 2):

This code extracts the last token from `attr` variable and store it in `date_` variable:

```
    rem split string to get date suffix
    set "newAttr="
    set "date_="
    FOR %%G IN ( "!attr:_=" "!" ) DO (
        SET "newAttr=!newAttr!_!date_!"
        SET "date_=%%~G"
    )
    SET "attr=!newAttr:~2!"
```

If you just need the last token, the code is simpler:

```
FOR %%G IN ( "!attr:_=" "!" ) DO SET "date_=%%~G"
```

Comment: I like this solution as it is only a few lines of code, +1! The string in `!attr!` must not contain any global wild-card characters like `*` and `?`...

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will be close to what you want (not sure whether `attr` will be what you need):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

IF EXIST Operatori_FULL.csv DEL Operatori_FULL.csv
IF EXIST Operatori_FULL.tmp DEL Operatori_FULL.tmp

FOR %%A IN ( Operatori_*.csv ) DO (
    :: get attribute from filename
    SET "attr=%%A"
    SET "attr=!attr:Operatori_=!"
    SET "attr=!attr:.csv=!"
    set "date_=!attr!"
    call :getLast
    :: dump CSVs, skipping each header line, adding the attributes from the filename
    FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=*" %%G IN ( %%A ) DO ECHO %%G;!attr!;!date_! >> Operatori_FULL.tmp
)

REN Operatori_FULL.tmp Operatori_FULL.csv
goto :eof

:getLast
    if "!date_:_=!" == "!date_!" goto :eof
    for /f "delims=_ tokens=1,*" %%g in ("!date_!") do set "date_=%h"
    goto :getLast
```

The subroutine `getLast` will strip `date_` to its last component (delimited by underscores).  Its operation is: while there's an underscore in `date_` it splits it into "the first token" and "all the rest" and sets `date_` to "all the rest". When there are no (more) underscores, `date_` is left with the last underscore-delimited component of its original value.

The "underscore stripping code" needs to be a "subroutine" since you cannot (to the best of my knowledge) use labels inside the outer `for` loop.

Comment: I try your code, but on every iteration the variable not change. Just remove the first token. I edited my question.

Comment: @TedGatiss I've updated the code: I'd missed (the significance of) the fact that you were already inside a `for` loop: this meant I needed `!` instead of `%` (which it looks like you spotted) but also I don't think labels can be used inside a `for` loop, so I've moved the code out of a loop and used `call`. Not exactly sure what you need `attr` to be, so there may be some tweaking needed for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution, that replaces every `_` by a line-break temporarily:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "STRING=%~1" & rem // (first argument is taken as input string)
set "CHAR=_"     & rem // (this is the character of interest)
rem // Build line-break:
(set ^"LF=^
%= empty line =%
^")

rem /* Replace each predefined character by a line-break,
rem    and enclose every line string portion within `""`;
rem    these quotation marks are needed to handle empty strings: */
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if defined STRING set ^"STRING=^"!STRING:%CHAR%=^"^%LF%%LF%^"!^"^"
rem /* Loop through all the lines in the modified string and
rem    assign each line string portion to a variable with
rem    the surrounding `""` removed; when the loop is finished,
rem    the last line is stored in the variable: */
for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%S in ("!STRING!") do (
    endlocal
    set "LAST=%%~S"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
)
rem // Return string portion behind last predefined character:
echo(!LAST!
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```